# How does <Component {...pageProps} /> function?

Tags: reactjs, state, shopify, next.js, react-component

newbie here,

The code Im learning from [this](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-demo-app-node-react/tree/charge-a-fee-using-the-billing-api-starter-files) and
I also find almost every _app.js have this line code too.

```
class Name extends App {
 render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    const config = { some config here };
    return (
        <AppProvider config = { config }>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AppProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that `<Component {...pageProps} />` part represents all other pages. And when I navigate page it change in pageprops.

It just I don't know how it call other page?

Answer (score 3):

`Component` is provided as a prop from whichever component is calling `Name` (lets call it `Foo`).

As you mentioned that navigation changes props, I am assuming that when page is navigated, this `Foo` undergoes some change and hence passes a different `Component` and/or `pageProps` to `Name`. Hence the `Component` instance in the new page gets new props.

If you want to call it in other pages, check how it has been passed from `Foo` and follow the same method in your component.